# Problem using shortest_path with find_nearest_link_within_distance function

Tags: pgrouting

I'm tried to work on the scenario that avoiding go through some path if there is a barrier near that path. It can run well with the query below:

```
SELECT * FROM shortest_path('SELECT gid AS id, source::int4, target::int4, shp_leng::double precision AS cost
    FROM network1
    where gid <> 35'
    ,18, 36, false, false);
```

Which means that the the path with gid 35 in the network1 table won't be taken into the calculation of shortest_path function.
But now, if I want to use find_nearest_link_within_distance function to fine the nearest path by a specific point, I got some problem, my code is like this:

```
SELECT * FROM shortest_path('SELECT gid AS id, source::int4, target::int4, shp_leng::double precision AS cost
    FROM network1
    where gid <> 
    (find_nearest_link_within_distance(
'POINT(120.218325 22.998469)',
0.5,
'network1'))'
    ,18, 36, false, false);
```

The error information:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "POINT"
```

LINE 5:     'POINT(120.218325 22.998469)',
Seems like find_nearest_link_within_distance can't be put between ' '.
I can't find the solution, can someone help me out with that?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem by adding a escape single quotes whenever a single quotes appear, just like this:

```
SELECT * FROM shortest_path('SELECT gid AS id, source::int4, target::int4, shp_leng::double precision AS cost
    FROM network1 where gid <>
    find_nearest_link_within_distance(''POINT(120.218325 22.998469)'', 0.1, ''network1'')',
    (SELECT id(foo.x)
FROM (
   SELECT find_node_by_nearest_link_within_distance(
    'POINT(120.222605 22.997879)',
    0.1,
    'network1')::link_point as x
) AS foo
),
    (SELECT id(foo.x)
FROM (
   SELECT find_node_by_nearest_link_within_distance(
    'POINT(120.22 23)',
    0.1,
    'network1')::link_point as x
) AS foo
),
    false, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with `... (SELECT find_nearest_link_within_distance(...)) ...`

Comment: I couldn't find this function in the standard PostGIS manual. Is this a custom function? where can I find it?

Comment: You can find these two functions in pgRouting.
Here is a detail tutorial about using pgRouting⇩
http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/a-beginners-guide-to-pgrouting/

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I've tried that before, but it still can't work and I receive the same error information...